# Extract bytes of specific stream from mpegts file using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, stream, metadata, mpeg2-ts

I have an mpeg-ts file with a single program. The program consists of some streams - one video stream and some metadata streams.

I would like to extract a specific stream to a separate file. However the metadata is encoded using a codec that ffmpeg doesn't know. I don't really care about this - I just want to extract the data as bytes, without the mpeg-ts container headers. I tried to use codec "copy" but with no success.

I tried the following:

```
    ffmpeg -i video.ts -map 0:1 -codec copy stream.txt
```

But ffmpeg says:

```
    Unable to find a suitable output format for stream.txt
```

The error above is only because ffmpeg doesn't know how to output a text file. So I tried to output with "rawvideo" container:

```
    ffmpeg -i video.ts -map 0:1 -codec copy -f rawvideo stream.txt
```

But:

```
    Cannot map stream #0:1 - unsupported type
```

Just to ensure that I can extract a content of an unknown codec I tried the following:

```
    ffmpeg -i video.ts -map 0:1 -codec copy stream.ts
```

But again:

```
    Cannot map stream #0:1 - unsupported type
```

So my questions are:

- Can I extract a byte stream of an unknown codec stream? and how?
- How can I output the byte stream without any container? Should I use the rawvideo?

Comment: try `ffmpeg -i video.ts -map 0:v -c:v copy stream.ts` or `ffmpeg -i video.ts -an -c:v copy stream.ts`

Comment: The command extracts the video stream. How can I extract the metadata?

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i video.ts -map 0:1 -codec copy -f data stream.txt
```

Comment: Is there some way to then decode the resulting txt into a readable info, for example in csv format?

Comment: That entirely depends on the format of the data stream. But don't count on ffmpeg for that.

Comment: Hi bro, I tried the following cmd:ffmpeg -i input.ts -map 0:2 -codec copy -f data -ignore_unknown -copy_unknown output.txt

Comment: it fails as:
```
Output #0, data, to 'output.txt':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
  Stream #0:0: Unknown: none ([128][0][0][0] / 0x0080)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:0 (copy)
[mpegts xxx] probed stream 2 failed
size= 0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss/-t/-frames parameters if used)
```
how to fix this?

Comment: You can't have both: `-ignore_unknown -copy_unknown`. Keep only the latter.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can do it with ffmpeg.
You can get some information with ffprobe but a better bet would be tstools.

```
tsinfo yourfile.ts > metadata.txt
```